# Create PHP to list down SSH usernames with their expiry dates

Tags: php, linux, ssh, debian

I would like to create a php that list down SSH usernames and their expiry dates from this script. I already wrote a script to list down all the ssh usernames with their expiry date in terminal. But how can I do this with PHP?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "-------------------------------"
echo "USERNAME          EXP DATE     "
echo "-------------------------------"
while read mumetndase
do
        USERLIST="$(echo $mumetndase | cut -d: -f1)"
        ID="$(echo $mumetndase | grep -v nobody | cut -d: -f3)"
        exp="$(chage -l $USERLIST | grep "Account expires" | awk -F": " '{print $2}')"
        if [[ $ID -ge 1000 ]]; then
        printf "%-17s %2s\n" "$USERLIST" "$exp"
        fi
done < /etc/passwd
TOTAL="$(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd | wc -l)"
echo "-------------------------------"
echo "Total Users: $TOTAL users"
echo "-------------------------------"
echo ""
```

Comment: Call the script from PHP?